# Integration inequality question help: Sketch the curve y=1/u for u > 0...

Tags: integration, inequality

Sketch the curve $y=\frac{1}{u}$ for $u > 0$. From the diagram, show that $\int\limits_1^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{du}{u}< \sqrt x-1$, for x > 1. Use this result to show that $0 < \ln(x) < 2(\sqrt{x}-1)$ and hence that $\frac{\ln x}{x}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$. Deduce that $x\ln(x)\to0$ as $x\to0$.

Basically, I figured out the first part in terms of it being from the diagram. From 'use this result' in the question, I don't know what to do next. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big Hint:

We know by the fundamental theorem of calculus that

$$\int_{1}^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{du}{u} = \frac{ln(x)}{2}.$$

However,

$$\int_{1}^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{du}{u} < \sqrt{x} -1.$$

Thus, we can say $$0<\frac{ln(x)}{2} < \sqrt{x} -1 \text{ or } 0<lnx<2(\sqrt{x} -1).$$

Now, if we divide by $x$ and apply Squeeze Theorem, one will quickly find what they asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some facts you can use:

$\displaystyle\int_1^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{u}du=\big[\ln u\big]_1^{\sqrt{x}}$, $\;\;\ln(\sqrt{x})=\frac{1}{2}\ln x$, $\;\;\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{x}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}, \;\;\ln\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)=-\ln t$